# Consulta MySQL. Cómo cambiar filas a columnas y agrupar resultados

Tags: mysql, sql

Intento cambiar filas a columnas con consulta mysql.
Esto es lo que tengo:

Consulta:

```
SELECT  c.municipio, 
if(p.resultado='RESULTADO_1', count(p.resultado),0) as RESULTADO_1, 
if(p.resultado='RESULTADO_2', count(p.resultado),0) as RESULTADO_2, 
if(p.resultado='RESULTADO_3', count(p.resultado),0) as RESULTADO_3, 
if(p.resultado='RESULTADO_4', count(p.resultado),0) as RESULTADO_4, 
if(p.resultado='RESULTADO_5', count(p.resultado),0) as RESULTADO_5 
FROM registros a left join cpostales b on (a.idcpostal=b.id) 
left join municipios c on (b.idmunicipio = c.id) 
left join puntos p on (a.id = p.idregistro) 
group by c.municipio, p.resultado
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que quiero obtener, es que en una sola fila me ponga todos los resultados de cada municipio, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta agrupar por alias.

Answer (score 0):

Atendiendo a lo que tienes hecho te propongo lo siguiente:

```
Select 
T.Municipio,
count(T.resultado_1), 
count(T.resultado_2),
count(T.resultado_3),
count(T.resultado_4),
count(T.resultado_5),
from
(
 SELECT  c.municipio, 
 if(p.resultado='RESULTADO_1', p.resultado, 0) as RESULTADO_1, 
 if(p.resultado='RESULTADO_2', p.resultado, 0) as RESULTADO_2, 
 if(p.resultado='RESULTADO_3', p.resultado, 0) as RESULTADO_3, 
 if(p.resultado='RESULTADO_4', p.resultado, 0) as RESULTADO_4, 
 if(p.resultado='RESULTADO_5', p.resultado, 0) as RESULTADO_5 
 FROM registros a left join cpostales b on (a.idcpostal=b.id) 
 left join municipios c on (b.idmunicipio = c.id) 
 left join puntos p on (a.id = p.idregistro) 
) T
group by T.municipio
```

Se hace una consulta interna (casi idéntica a la que tienes tú ya hecha), la cual sirve para relacionar todas las tablas implicadas y proyectar las columnas deseadas, y es sobre esta consulta que se hace una consulta más general la cual es la que va a aplicar el **operador group by** por el **campo municipio**, y aplica además la **función de agregación count** a los campos deseados que van en la **claúsula select**.

Answer (score 0):

Se solucionó cambiando la línea:

```
if(p.resultado='RESULTADO_1', count(p.resultado),0) as RESULTADO_1,
```

por:

```
sum(case when p.resultado='RESULTADO_1' then 1 else 0 end)
```